# What do you call a keyboard with a bar-shaped Enter key?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, carriage-return

I'm a programmer, and a touch-typist, and so type best when the keys I use are where I expect them to be. Perhaps because I'm American, and do most of my work on Apple computers, I expect the keyboard to have a bar-shaped Enter key, a backslash/pipe key immediately above the enter key, and a bar-shaped backspace key:

Dell keyboard with bar-shaped return key:

[image: Dell keyboard with bar-shaped return key]

Unfortunately, when I order new (non-Apple) equipment I often receive keyboards with a completely different L-shaped return key, the backslash/pipe key placed in the top row, and a teenie backspace key:

Gateway keyboard with L-shaped return key:

[image: Gateway keyboard with L-shaped return key]

Keyboards like this drive me nuts, and I'd like to avoid them as much as possible. However, here's the problem: I don't know what to call the keyboard layout that I prefer, so I can't read a computer's specs and know whether it includes a "good" keyboard.

Without a specific term for this type of keyboard, I'm reduced to examining any image I can see of the keyboard, looking for the shape of the return key. Even then, I'll sometimes see a "good" keyboard in the marketing material, but when my order actually arrives it will include a "bad" keyboard. (BTW, I'm sure there are those who love L-shaped return keys, and I mean no disrespect by calling such keyboards "bad", but when evaluated in the light of my personal needs that is what they are.)

They're all QWERTY keyboards, but is there a keyboard layout name which specifies what I want?

Comment: Keyboards are cheap and interchangeable (except for laptops, obviously); buy one that you know you like and throw away the one that came with the computer.

Comment: I don't see how this has anything to do with the keyboards being "non-Apple"; more like being from the 1970s. I haven't seen a tiny backspace key like that in decades.

Comment: I overcome this kind of problems by making sure to see the product's appearance before the purchase for product types where it matters (basically, everything outside the system unit).

Comment: The AZERTY layout used in France has an L-shaped return key too: on my 486 I used to have to dismantle the enter key to access to the `\` for some progress where AltGr wouldn't work.

Comment: Wow! One of the old programmable Gateway2000 keyboards! Those things were GREAT! You can probably get a ton of money for this on Ebay!

Comment: Bar-shaped Enter key?  I'd call it a great place to have a drink!

Comment: Both of the keyboard pictures were found trolling on Wikimedia Commons. And yes, I used to have a Gateway2000 programmable keyboard. The chief thing I remember is accidentally programming it to do something strange, and then being flummoxed on how to un-program it.

Comment: I'm a programmer too. While developing most code lines are short and we constantly hit Enter key while executing commands in console. So this key is very important and should be big and easy to hit. Your problem is you don't find it because you're not familiar with the keyboard. But big L shaped Enter key is better for programmers, not the small bar one you showed us on picture.

Comment: @derloopkat You could use the same reasoning to argue that the best keyboards for programmers have ALL large keys. Doesn't work for me, though... ;)

Comment: Also a programmer here. I also prefer the mirrored L-shaped return key, but I really think that just comes down to the nostalgia factor I get from it. I always find a bar shaped ANSI enter key just fine. I do think that sacrificing an extended length backspace bar is not appealing. I'd rather lose right shift altogether.

Comment: Being a touch typist myself I REALLY HATE bar shaped Enter key. Look at your right pinky when you 're typing, it's supposed to be in vertical position when it hits Enter. With bar shaped Enter I always hit back slash instead. Arrrgrrrr

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The [Gateway keyboard in your image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0VXC.jpg) is definitely **not the British/UK keyboard layout** (as mentioned in the other answer), which doesn't only have different *symbol positions* but also different *key shapes*. Its <kbd>Enter ↵</kbd> key is a mirrored `⨼` L shape like the symbol `↵` instead of a 180°-rotated one `Ꞁ` like on the ISO, UK and German keyboards. It has the [Backwards-L layout](https://deskthority.net/wiki/Return_key#Backwards_L-shaped) and the bar-shaped version has the [ANSI layout](https://deskthority.net/wiki/Return_key#ANSI)

[image: All Enter key shapes]

> ## [Backwards L-shaped](https://deskthority.net/wiki/Return_key#Backwards_L-shaped)
>
> A *"backwards-L shaped"* (or just *"L-shaped"*) Return key is the union of the ISO and ANSI <kbd>Return</kbd> keys. The key is often called Big-ass Enter because of its size, or Asian enter because it is found on many East Asian keyboards.
>
> There have been studies that have shown it to be easier to hit accurately than the ISO and ANSI Return keys.
>
> However, with the backwards-L shaped Return key, the `\` key has to be relocated, often at the expense of having a smaller <kbd>backspace</kbd> or <kbd>right shift</kbd> key.

Many many people call it the J-shaped enter key as well. Here is the real US keyboard with that layout

[image: Backwards-L enter with smaller shift]

compared to the British one with completely different keys for the symbols

[image: UK keyboard]

> When you see the single-row <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, that is the US-ANSI layout. IBM suffered terribly when it added an extra key between <kbd>Left-Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Z</kbd> on the Selectric III, so when it came to designing the Extended Layout with which most of us are now familiar, someone recognised the folly of the Selectric III and suggested cutting the large enter key in half to accommodate the `\` key.
>
> On ISO keyboards, the Enter key is usually still the size of the ANSI Enter plus the `\` key and, prior to MS messing up the bottom row with the Windows keys, the `\` was often placed in the single space position between Ctrl and Alt. Since the introduction of <kbd>Windows</kbd> keys, the placement of `\` on ISO keyboards has wandered. Sometimes, the Enter key is narrowed at the bottom so that `\` can sit beside `“`. Sometimes the Backspace key is halved so that `\` sits beside `=`. The last and least desired placement is back in that increasingly annoying position of between <kbd>Left-Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Z</kbd>.
>
> [What's the advantage of a L-shaped "enter" key vs. a regular (one-row high) "enter" key?](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-advantage-of-a-L-shaped-enter-key-vs-a-regular-one-row-high-enter-key)

IIRC in the past (like 15-20 years ago or more) I've always seen the backwards-L enter key in my country (Vietnam), which uses standard US keyboard layout. On most keyboards the backslash is put on the left of <kbd>R-Shift</kbd> key like in the first image, which results in a better typing experience since no keys are too small. On some others it's moved to the left of backspace, resulting in a tiny square backslash key without text label, only a symbol like in the below image. And then when laptops became more common the desktop keyboards began changing to the ANSI rectangular enter key like that.

[image]

<sup>A little bit of my own history: I remembered around 1995-1997 I went to my uncle's house and while playing some spacecraft shooting game I realized that there are 2 similar keys named <kbd>←</kbd> (as you can see in the big-ass keyboard above). I tried pressing the upper one (which turns out to be the backspace) to see if it moves left or not and suddenly I got a much stronger weapon and easily passed level 5, which no one could do before</sup>

While searching on the internet I also find a strange layout where the **backslash is moved to the right of the <kbd>R-Shift</kbd> key**. I don't think anyone will be a fan of this, since typing a backslash is now too hard

[image: Keyboard with backslash on the right of R-Shift]

FYI **Apple did produce keyboards in backwards-L layout** like that

[image: Apple keyboard with backwards-L layout]

Here is a [detailed comparison between layouts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#/media/File:Physical_keyboard_layouts_comparison_ANSI_ISO_KS_ABNT_JIS.png)

[image: layout comparison]

> A comparison of common mechanical computer keyboard layouts. Keys that are not present in them all are highlighted in pink (alphanumeric) and dark-grey (modifier). Keys that are sometimes omitted are shown with interrupted outlines. Note that the 104th key on the ABNT layout is located in the numpad section and therefore not visible. From left to right, top to bottom:
>
> - 101 keyboard, common in North America, Asia, Oceania
> - 101 alternate, common in Asia and Russia
> - 102 keyboard, common in Europe, Latin America
> - 103 keyboard, used in South Korea
> - 104 keyboard, used in Brazil
> - 106 keyboard, used in Japan
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#Physical_layouts

The second version is common in Asia and Russia, which explains why I saw them a lot in the past

You can also see various types of <kbd>Enter ↵</kbd> key if you open [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22339)

[image: MKLC Enter key]

## Further reading

- [What happened to upside down L shaped enter keys?](https://www.quora.com/What-happened-to-upside-down-L-shaped-enter-keys)
- [Why do some keyboards extend the Return key up into the backslash?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/58519/43036)
- [Why oh why are more keyboards ditching the L-shaped Enter key?](https://msfn.org/board/topic/104615-why-oh-why-are-more-keyboards-ditching-the-l-shaped-enter-key/)
- [J-Shaped Return Keys](https://geekhack.org/index.php?topic=13697.0)
- [any chance to order a keyboard with this (customized) layout?](https://deskthority.net/keyboards-f2/any-chance-to-order-a-keyboard-with-this-customized-layout-t18836.html)

Comment: Whoa! Nice answer! Thanks! (And good work giving sources for everything.)

Comment: "There have been studies that have shown it to be easier to hit accurately than the ISO and ANSI Return keys." ❤️

Answer (score 33):

[Apparently the 'bar' shaped return key is a US layout and the reverse L-shaped return key is a UK/ISO layout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_and_American_keyboards) - When *specifically* requesting a reverse L-shaped return key, you can probably ask for an ISO layout keyboard. The bar-shaped enter key is an *ANSI* layout (according to the comment by the OP).

In my experience the US layout is *much* more common on laptops (though, I have a British layout Thinkpad), and most English language desktop keyboards outside the UK seem to have bar-style enter keys.

Comment: Ahah! Chasing that reference gives me the answer: the "US layout" is actually an [ANSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_National_Standards_Institute) layout. Bingo!

Comment: Other keys aside, the "L-shaped" Enter key derives from the IBM Selectric keyboard. 

Its proper name is therefore "correct." :D

Comment: Considering the intent of the question, I intentionally chose not to mention this little fact ;p.

Comment: 'most common desktop keyboards outside the UK' -- I can state that Croatian keyboards are usually (and preferably to Croats) ISO layout, so I'm not sure the 'outside the UK' statement is accurate, especially given it references to a very, very large portion of the world.

Comment: @IvanVučica It's not accurate. [German keyboards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_keyboard_layout) have a vertical return key. Perhaps "english language keyboards outside the UK" would be a better expression

Comment: Edited to reflect that this talks about english keyboards.