# What are the differences between these two keyboard layouts?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

What is the difference and layout name of this first keyboard:

[image]

and this second keyboard:
[image]

Second keyboard layout is ANSI (correct me if im wrong)

The first keyboard is Logitech G512, product code (920-008946)

Is the first one considered ISO layout? But on ISO layouts the left shift is smaller but in this case its not? Then what is the difference and what layout name does the first one have?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do you call a keyboard with a bar-shaped Enter key?](https://superuser.com/questions/837448/what-do-you-call-a-keyboard-with-a-bar-shaped-enter-key)

Comment: @Rango I have read that post but I don't see the layout of the first one in any of the [images](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#/media/File:Physical_keyboard_layouts_comparison_ANSI_ISO_KS_ABNT_JIS.png).

Comment: All of them either have the correct enter key and then different backspace or shift key, in this case the only difference between the ones I have linked is the enter key is from ANSI layout and that's it (also moving the slash to the top of enter). Is this just a custom layout that only Logitech provides or there is some generalized name?

Comment: The biggest difference is the region they are used. European regions tend to use the longer enter key spanning two rows, where american keyboards use the single-line enter key. In the past Logitech would not even sell american keyboard layouts to europe. Not sure if they do today though, I switched to alternate brands that don't follow these standards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those appear to be Logitech G512 "Carbon" gaming keyboards.

The first one is a variant of the **ISO** layout. Many ISO layouts have a smaller left shift key to accommodate an extra key to the right of it. For example, the ISO-UK layout (105 keys) has a `\|` key there.

[image: ISO keyboard layout]

The **JIS** layout seems to have the same shaped enter key as ISO but with the same sized left-shift as ANSI. However it has a lot of other differences not seen in your first keyboard.

### [image: JIS keyboard layout]

The second one is the **ANSI** layout (104 keys).

[image: ANSI keyboard layout]

---

I think these both were first introduced with the IBM Model M keyboard but aspects of the layouts originate with the IBM Model F keyboard with it's characteristically large enter key.

[image: IBM Model F keyboard layout]

Nowadays almost all keyboards fall into the ISO or ANSI physical layouts, regardless of country specific key-mappings and key-markings.

Even smaller format keyboards like TKL, 75% 70% 65% or 60% layouts keep to ISO or ANSI layouts for the main block of keys.

[image: 60% Layout]

Really small keyboards like 40% or Planck, whether ortholinear or staggered, don't really fall into either camp. Neither do most, but not all, ergonomic layouts.

[image: Planck keyboard layout]